# Most computational efficient way for list of random numbers in Tensroflow given a list of maxiumum values like in `np.random.randint`

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

For `np.random.randint`, you can input a list of maximum values, and get a list of random ints from 0 to those maximum values.

```
np.random.randint([1, 10, 100, 1000] )

>array([  0,   7,  31, 348])
```

Tensorflow `tf.random.uniform` doesn't allow lists for `maxval`, so you need to either create a statement for each, or run a loop. I was wondering if there was more elegant way to get these random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tensorflow 2.2, you can find `maxval` in `uniform` function

```
tf.random.uniform(  [4], minval=[0, 0, 0, 0], maxval=[1, 10, 100, 1000] )

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([  0.99932146,   4.725709  ,  34.502377  , 184.38554   ],
  dtype=float32)>
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/uniform

Comment: This works, although not when I set `dtype=tf.dtypes.int32` , I get `InvalidArgumentError: maxval must be 0-D, got shape [5] [Op:RandomUniformInt]` . Any idea why maxval won't take a list when generating ints?

Comment: from the source code https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py#L263, it mentioned that `for integer types, broadcasting is not supported, so it needs to be a scalar`. I believe this is caused by the implementation of the function and it is known to the dev. Perhaps they should update the official api document of `random/uniform` later to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer would be to first generate the numbers without the max lengths, then use the mod operator

```
randos = tf.random.uniform(
    shape=[a.shape[0]], minval=0, maxval=6, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32, seed=None, name=None
)


limitedRandos = tf.math.floormod(
    randos, lengths+1, name=None
)
```